# Draw a basic tree from recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to learn recursion but am not really understanding it at all.
Can somebody please show me example code to build a tree like this? As I feel it will help seeing graphic recursions

[image: Tree]

Assuming there is a line method with parameters for the top and bottom x and y coordinates how would I go about this?

Thanks! also any recommended tutorials etc on recursion?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  StackOverflow is not a tutorial or discussion site.  You are expected to make an effort to solve the problem (do research, write code, etc) and then ask a _specific_ question about your code when you run into a problem.

Comment: You're begging for code without even posting an attempt. Please don't harm your brain by denying it the chance to try first, and more importantly, please don't insult your brain by thinking that it's not able to try first. I'm completely dumbfounded.

Comment: think about it from a flow standpoint. if you want to show leaves first, then you'll need a check to see if you are at a leaf node in your recursive method. also consider how recursive method is helpful in generating this tree (like traversal?). build it up in parts and try to visualize the flow in pseudo-code first. good luck

Comment: It is **recursive** because you execute the same function in every node. So you need to figure out the algorithm that handles a **single node**, and while doing so it processes the **neighbouring nodes** by **calling the same algorithm on those nodes**. (call the method on the other nodes). Make sure that there is an exit point for example `if(this.data == null) return;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are many different ways you could achieve this recursively -- here is one of them:

```
public void drawTree(Graphics g, int x, int y, int arity, int depth) {
    if (depth > 0) {
        int childDistanceX = (int) (Math.pow(arity, depth) * DISTANCE_X);
        int childX = x - (arity - 1) * childDistanceX / 2;
        int childY = y - DISTANCE_Y;

        for (int child = 0; child < arity; child++) {
            g.drawLine(x, y, childX, childY);
            drawTree(g, childX, childY, arity, depth - 1);
            childX += childDistanceX;
        }
    }
}
```

Given the `x,y` coordinates of the root node, the number of children (`arity`) and the `depth` of the tree, this method first computes the horizontal distance between the child nodes based on a constant `DISTANCE_X` which is the horizontal gap between leaf nodes.

With this information, and with a second constant `DISTANCE_Y` that gives the vertical distance beetween the different levels of the tree, we can compute the `x,y` position of the root node's left-most child.

Then it's just a matter of iterating over all child nodes and drawing a line from the root to the child. This is also where the recursion comes into play: we call the method recursively, but each time the current child becomes the new root. Note also that the depth of the subtree governed by a child is one less than that of its parent, so we pass `depth - 1` in the recursive call.

You can try out the above method by copy & pasting it into the following class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TreeTest extends JPanel {
    private static final int DISTANCE_X = 4;
    private static final int DISTANCE_Y = 60;

    private int treeArity = 3;
    private int treeDepth = 3;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Dimension size = getSize();
        int x = size.width / 2;
        int y = (size.height + treeDepth * DISTANCE_Y) / 2;

        drawTree(g, x, y, treeArity, treeDepth);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TreeTest main = new TreeTest();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(main);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```